# I want to tag documents to make search easier

Tags: 2010, keyword

first time I try to work 2010 search functionality.

I need to be able to tag documents in a document library, so that my users can type in keywords that will lead to those documents.  I know sharepoint searchs within the documents, but my files are saved in web format, and for whatever reason it does not search the document content.

So I enabled the Enterprise keyword feature in the library, added keywords to a couple of documents, but when I do the search, I don't get the documents in my search result.

How does this feature actually work?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: How do you "do the search"? Is this about the SharePoint Search service? Has it been configured in your farm? Search results don't magically appear. A lot of work goes into configuring search. And even then, search results depend on the crawled data. If an item is tagged, it will only appear in the search results after the next crawl, not immediately.

Comment: I search by using the default search box web part.  Do you have information on how to configure the search?  Also, what exactly is meant by "crawled data"?  I've been done many things in our share point site but mainly out of the box solutions, so my knowledge here is rather limited, any resources you can share will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Search in SharePoint 2010 does not just happen. The Search Service needs to be set up and configured. To get started with planning and configuring search, please refer to

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263400(v=office.14).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by metadata ( I think only one though). See more info at http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-HA102832523.aspx